# How to find angle between $2$ points in $3D$ space?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I think I am not able to convey what I need so here is the edited question:

[image: plot image]

As you can see in the image, a point on the left is at $(-3,-3,0)$ and the point on the right is at $(3,3,0)$.

And when I draw the cylinder it spawns at $(0,0,0)$, the center point of the cylinder is at $(0,0,0)$ and size of the cylinder is the distance between $2$ points. Now my goal is to rotate the cylinder in all $x$, $y$ and $z$-axis so that it connects both the points.

Here this is a $2$D image so I know that I will need to rotate this only in z-axis but I want a generalized for the points anywhere in the coordinate system.

Comment: What is the initial orientation of your cylinder? Which vector is its starting axis?

Comment: Starting axis is the origin and my code draws cylinder vertically at the origin.

Comment: So, the initial axis is $(0,0,1)$, and you want to rotate to the axis which is the vector from $(1,0,0)$ to $(1,1,1)$?

Comment: The question you asked is not the information you need to know. You need to know the rotation matrix from the axis of your initial cylinder to the vector $(0,1,1).$ To build this matrix you can use an angle (but not the angle you asked for!) _and_ an axis of rotation, or you can use other methods.

Comment: Related [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2356714/3301) (at least the extracting an angle part).

Answer (score 3):

A straightforward way is to use the dot or scalar product of two vectors.
$$ \vec{u}\cdot \vec{v} = |\vec{u}||\vec{v}|\cos\theta $$ 
Here $\theta$ is the angle formed by $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ when they are tail-to-tail.
$\vec{u}\cdot \vec{v}$ is easy to compute using components as
$\vec{u}\cdot \vec{v} = u_1v_1 + u_2v_2 + u_3v_3$ so
$$\cos\theta = \frac{u_1v_1 + u_2v_2 + u_3v_3}{\sqrt{u_1^2+u_2^2+u_3^2}\sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2+v_3^2}}\ .$$

In your case you have
$$\cos\theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\ .$$

---

OK, I'll try to use the above to answer the clarified question:

I will assume that your cylinder *spawns* with the $z$-axis as the cylinder axis.  If this is not true, then you will have to modify what follows.  You talk about rotating about all $x$, $y$, and $z$-axis, but actually only two rotations are necessary to rotate a vector that points in the positive $z$-direction to point in an arbitrary direction.  Suppose you want to rotate the vector $\vec{k}$ to point in the direction $<a_1,a_2,a_3>$.

[image: spherical coordinates]

By Dmcq (Own work) [[CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0)], [via Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3A3D_Spherical_2.svg)

The angle $\varphi$ is the angle between $\vec{k}$ and $\vec{a}$ and can be found from the above as
$$ \varphi = \arccos\left(\frac{a_3}{\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2}}\right)$$

The angle $\theta$ is the angle between the positive $x$-axis and the projection of $\vec{a}$ onto the $xy$-plane.
$$ \theta = \arccos\left(\frac{<1,0,0>\cdot<a_1,a_2,0>}{|<a_1,a_2,0>|}\right)
          = \arccos\left(\frac{a_1}{\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}}\right)$$
The expression for $\theta$ is only true if $0\leq\theta\leq 180$.  If $\theta >180$ ($y<0$) you will have to patch it up.

Take your cylinder, rotate by $\varphi$ about the $y$-axis (counter-clockwise looking at the $xz$-plane from the positive $y$-axis), then rotate by $\theta$ about the $z$-axis.

Comment: It is the same answer as previous one and my question is the original position of the cylinder is at (0,0,0) so after finding the 'Theta' value how can I apply rotation in all x,y,z-axis to make it align to the direction this is facing?

Comment: Yes, I was typing it at the same time.  This is the answer to your question, if this is not the question that you need answered then you need to clarify your question.

Comment: I'm not getting that same answer. Note that the target orientation is actually the vector $(0,1,1)$

Comment: " have 2 points in 3-dimensional space and I want to find the angle between them with respect to the origin as I have to draw a cylinder between them."  _The angle between them with respect to the origin_ is not the angle between $<0,0,1>$ and $<1,1,1>$?  Ok, then the question is even less clear to me.

Comment: @Malcolm my apologies if I am not able to convey the information properly. I have updated the question please check it.

Answer (score 2):

Angle between $(a,b,c)$ and $(x,y,z)$ is given by,
$$\cos\theta =\frac{ax+by+cz}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$

The unit vector from $(a,b,c)$ to $(x,y,z)$ will be$$\frac{a-x}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}i+\frac{b-y}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}j+\frac{c-z}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}k$$
Here the $i^{th}$ term is Cosine of angle with x-axis,

$j^{th}$ term is Cosine of angle with y-axis ,

$k^{th}$ term is Cosine of angle with z-axis.

Comment: I think I might need rotation vector between in all directions because I have to rotate in all the three directions and I don't know how to use theta value to achieve what I need.

Comment: I updated the answer @Samvid Jhaveri

Comment: So I need to rotate in x,y and z direction by the angles I find from i, j and k right?

Comment: Yes, precisely, if you give initial unit vector, i can give you angles too

Comment: Hope the additional information i have helps

Answer (score 2):

Samvid,

If the center of the cylinder is at the origin then the axis of the cylinder is a line through the origin: use X=<0,0,0> in my answer above.  Still to be determined are r and h.

In other words, suppose that A is a unit vector along the axis of the cylinder.  Then we use the same idea as in my previous answer, namely build circles on the axis

cylinder(t,$\alpha$)=t A + r (cos($\alpha$) + sin($\alpha$)) where t $\epsilon$[${-h} \over {2}$,$h \over 2 $] and $\alpha \epsilon [0,2\pi]$

Somehow the other two points must be used to determine r and h and A.

Comment: But I think I can move the cylinder to one point, i.e. (-3,-3,0) and then how can I rotate it towards another point?

Comment: I still don't know what you are trying to accomplish or why.  You somehow have a cylinder of unspecified height and radius with its center at the origin.  You want the do rigid rotations and translations of this cylinder to move it to some other place and some other orientation.  (Limiting yourself to rotations and translations means that the height and radius will not change.)

Comment: If you want to do a rigid rotation of the axis from its (apparent) starting position along the z axis to some other vector, v, this is a rotation around the axis determined by the cross product of the z axis with v through an angle determined by the arccos formula above.

Answer (score 2):

You have two vectors $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$ and you want the angle between them. The answer is

$$\theta = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\| {\bf v}_1 \times {\bf v}_2  \|}{{\bf v}_1 \cdot {\bf v}_2} \right)$$

In terms of an algorithm see **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21486462/380384)** with code and an example.

I tent to use the [Atan2(y,x)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2.aspx) function because it handles the fringe cases better. When the two vectors are perpendicular the methods that rely on `Acos()` can fail. And the methods that use `Asin()` fail when the two vectors are parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Samvid

Just so that we are clear:  you are working with an application that creates a "generic" cylinder with its center at the origin and you need to move it to some other position in your project.  Is this correct?

You also need to change its orientation, right?

How about its height?  Can you create it with the correct height or do you need to stretch (or contract) it yourself?

Same for the radius...

If these are all correct, please describe what you know about the "spawned" cylinder.

Answer (score 0):

Two points as vectors: X and Y.  The angle between them is the arccos of the ratio of the dot product to the product of the lengths of the vectors:

$\alpha = arccos ({{X.Y} \over {||X|| ||Y||}})$

where ||X|| = $ \sqrt {X.X} $

is the norm (length) of the vector X = $<x_1,x_2,x_3>$

and

V.W = $v_1 w_1+v_2 w_2 + v_3 w_3$

is the usual dot product.

I am not sure that I see what this has to do with your problem, though.  How, exactly, is the cylinder determined by the three points (O,X,Y)?

As a guess, suppose that you want a cylinder with the center of the base at X = <1,0,0> and center of the top at Y = <1,1,1> and radius r.  Then you would simply determine the line from X to Y (line(t) = t X + (1-t) Y for t $\epsilon [0,1])  $ build a circle around it:

cylinder[t,$ \alpha $] = line[t]+ $ r (cos(\alpha) perp_1 + sin( \alpha ) perp_2 )$ with t $\epsilon$ [0,1] and $\alpha \epsilon$[0,2 $\pi$].

where $perp_1 $ and $perp_2$ are mutually perpendicular unit vectors perpendicular to the line.

Comment: No the center of the cylinder is  at (0,0,0).

Comment: Samvid  Need more information: what role do <1,0,0> and <1,1,1> play in the construction of the cylinder.

Comment: my apologies if I am not able to convey information properly. I have edited the question. Please check that.